# Can somebody tell me why this simple PHP loop doesn't work?

Tags: php, loops, syntax-error

I just wanted to write a simple loop that counts up in +10 steps until it is larger than the number and reverts back to the last +10 step, this is just a test loop so I could try out the loop mechanics before implementing it in my real code, but for some reason it either just doesn't compile or spits out real random stuff.
[output from an online php sandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLK6o.png)

Am I doing something horribly wrong or why is it putting out demonic symbols instead of a simple number.

```
<?php
    $get_id_folder_number = 0;
    $test_value = 12;

      WHILE($test_value > $get_id_folder_number)
      {
          echo $get_id_folder_number;

        //add 10
        $get_id_folder_number + 10;

      }
      if($test_value < $get_id_folder_number)
      {
        $get_id_folder_number -10;
      }


echo $get_id_folder_number;
```

Comment: `$get_id_folder_number + 10;` doesn't store the value anywhere, try `$get_id_folder_number += 10;` (with the added `=`), same as `$get_id_folder_number -10;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I see, you are in an infinite loop because you never change the value of your variable, you must do this :

```
while ($test_value > $get_id_folder_number) {
    echo $get_id_folder_number;

    //add 10
    $get_id_folder_number += 10; // or $get_id_folder_number = $get_id_folder_number + 10
}
```

because in your example you make the addition but never setting the result in the variable.
Same thing for you `if`

```
if ($test_value < $get_id_folder_number) {
    $get_id_folder_number -= 10;
}
```